# Разница в запросе между MS SQL и PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Знаю как написать запрос в MS SQL

```
select m.date, count(*) as count,
        (select count(*) from posts n where n.date <= m.date) ) as total 
from posts m 
group by m.date order by 1
```

Но в PostgreSQL этот запрос не работает. Ошибка вокруг from. 
как правильно переписать запрос? 
может сервер PostgreSQL  иначе читает запросы чем MS SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Этот запрос не может работать ни в одной СУБД потому как в нем банальная ошибка синтаксиса - лишняя закрывающаяся скобка перед `as`.

Но по хорошему и в MS SQL и в postgresql, стоит избавится от подзапроса и переписать его так:

```
select m.date, count(*) as count,
       sum(count(*)) over(order by date) as total
  from posts m 
 group by m.date order by 1
```